# How to add different color shades in the background of a plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

I would like to shade different parts of my plot different colors. I have tried the following:

```
boxplot(DEMAND~INTERVAL, data = NewData, main = "Box Plot for Each 15-minute Interval", xlab = "Interval", ylab = "Demand (kW)", col="dark grey", border = "black")
rect(0,0,44,1,col = rgb(0,1,0,1/15))
rect(44,0,56,1,col = rgb(1,1,0,1/15))
rect(56,0,76,1,col = rgb(1,0,0,1/15))
rect(76,0,92,1,col = rgb(1,1,0,1/15))
rect(92,0,96,1,col = rgb(0,1,0,1/15))
```

This produces the following:

[image: plot]

But is it possible to make the plot such that the box and whiskers are shown on top of the added rectangles? Also, how can I ensure that the entire plot is covered such that there are no overhanging white areas?

Answer (score 0):

This will not be the most elegant, but the simples solution.

1) To cover the entire region - do not start your rectangles at 0, let them start at x-values below 0 and y-values below 0.

2) To bring boxplots in front of the plot, call the boxplot again, after you added the rectangles, one more time, with `add=TRUE`

Here is a demo:

```
boxplot(weight ~ feed, data=chickwts)
rect(-1000, -1000, 1.5, 1000, col=adjustcolor("red", 0.1))
rect(1.5, -1000, 3.5, 1000, col=adjustcolor("orange", 0.1))
rect(3.5, -1000, 5.5, 1000, col=adjustcolor("blue", 0.1))
rect(5.5, -1000, 1000, 1000, col=adjustcolor("green", 0.1))
boxplot(weight ~ feed, data=chickwts, add=TRUE)
```

[image: box1]

For a more elegant solution: start with an empty plot, add rectangles, then add boxes at the end.

```
colors <- c("red", "orange", "blue", "green")

plot.new()
plot.window(xlim=c(0.5, length(unique(chickwts$feed))+0.5), ylim=range(chickwts$weight))
rect(c(-1000,1.5,3.5,5.5), -1000, c(1.5,3.5,5.5,1000), 1000, col=adjustcolor(colors, 0.1))
boxplot(weight ~ feed, data=chickwts, add=TRUE)
```

Which will give you the same result.

Comment: Is there no way to get the plot to start at the left side of the most left box, rather than just shading in the white area? That is, for my plot to start right at zero

Comment: @user23985723985 for that - adjust the "xlim" argument. Try using `xlim=c(1, ...)` instead of `xlim=c(0.5, ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using base graphics, you need to create an empty `plot` first, add the `rect`angles, then plot the real data.

### Before

```r
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray")
rect(0.5,0,4,26, col = rgb(0,1,0,1/15))
rect(4,0,6.5,26, col = rgb(1,1,0,1/15))
```

[image: before]

### After

```r
bp <- boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, plot = FALSE)
xrange <- c(1L, length(bp$names)) + c(-0.5, 0.5)
yrange <- range(bp$stats)
plot(NA, type = "n", xlim = xrange, ylim = yrange,
     xaxt = "n", xlab = NA, ylab = NA)
axis(1, at = seq_along(bp$names), labels = bp$names)
rect(0.5,0,4,26, col = rgb(0,1,0,1/15))
rect(4,0,6.5,26, col = rgb(1,1,0,1/15))
boxplot(count ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, col = "lightgray", add = TRUE)
```

[image: after]

(Notice that the `"lightgray"` filling is not color-tinted in the second plot.)

In this case, I'm not plotting the data twice. The first call produces no plot but returns data we need (assuming you need to do this somewhat programmatically).